# Implementation of ApplySort method from IBindingList

Tags: c#, sorting

I am currently developing a family of keyed collections, and I wanted to have one which would implement the `IBindingList` interface.

My `BindingKeyedCollection` is derived from a `KeyedCollection` which owns a look-up dictionary, used to make the researches by key.

However, I have suspicions about my implementation of the `ApplySort` method (a method used to sort the collection relatively to one of the items property). It seems to be working as it is now, but I am not sure that all items are synchronized properly.

```
protected virtual void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        this.SortProperty = property;
        this.SortDirection = direction;
        if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            ResetItems(this.OrderBy(item => property.GetValue(item)).ToList());
            IsSorted = true;
            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, property));
        }
        else if (direction == ListSortDirection.Descending)
        {
            ResetItems(this.OrderByDescending(item => property.GetValue(item)).ToList());
            IsSorted = true;
            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, property));
        }
    }
```

Basically I am using LINQ to order another collection and change its `Item`s list with the main one.

```
private void ResetItems(List<TItem> items)
    {
        base.ClearItems();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            base.InsertItem(IndexOf(item), item);
        }
    }
```

I would like to have an external opinion on this way of sorting my collection, if they are any flaws that I would have missed, and if so, is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: Those methods are inherited from Collection<T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ApplySortCore()` method could be made more dry

```
protected virtual void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction)
{
    this.SortProperty = property;
    this.SortDirection = direction;

    IEnumerable<T> items = null;
    if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        items = this.OrderBy(item => property.GetValue(item));
    }
    else
    {
        items = this.OrderByDescending(item => property.GetValue(item));
    }

    ResetItems(items.ToList ());

    IsSorted = true;
    OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, property));
}
```

---

You should always try to code against interfaces instead of a concrete implementation.

In the `ResetItems()` method you should either use an `IList<TItem>` or better an `IEnumerable<TItem>` for the input parameter.

---

The call to this `IndexOf()` method seems a little bit strange. You already have the items sorted why don't you just add the items one by one ?

Because the methods are inherited from `Collection<T>` we can use the `Add()` method which simplifies the `ResetItems()` method to

```
private void ResetItems(IEnumerbale<TItem> items)
{
    base.ClearItems();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `.ToList()` on `items` before passing it to `ResetItems`.

Comment: Why do you think so ? @DanLyons

Comment: `items` is built by enumerating `this`.  `ResetItems` calls `base.ClearItems()` before enumerating `items`.  Due to the deferred execution of LINQ, `items` will be empty by the time you hit the `foreach` inside `ResetItems`.  Even without the clear, the `foreach` would throw an exception because it modifies the same collection it is enumerating.

Comment: Good catch. Updated.

Comment: Thank you for your help, 
Indeed Dan Lyons was right, Items was empty when trying to add the new items, but adding ToList() solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Triggering the change event with `OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, property));` is (probably) wrong, or at least not recommended/is unintended.

The documentation for [`ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType, PropertyDescriptor)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_ListChangedEventArgs__ctor_System_ComponentModel_ListChangedType_System_ComponentModel_PropertyDescriptor_) explicitly says:

> This constructor can be used only if the schema of the object has changed.
>
> The listChangedType parameter should be PropertyDescriptorAdded, PropertyDescriptorChanged, or PropertyDescriptorDeleted.

So it is not in fact intended for item data changes.

The documentation on the event is still a bit lacking, and I requested clarification on it ([1](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/1907), [2](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/1908)), so hopefully it will be clearer soon.

But looking at the implementation of `DataView` hints at the intended use for entire list changes: [`DataView` defines a `ResetEventArgs` field with `OldIndex = -1` and `NewIndex = -1`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataView.cs,580db5e53398e044,references), and uses that to indicate entire list data changes.

So you should trigger the event instead with:

```cs
    OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
```